# Underscore to filter array object using another array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to get specific properties from array b. Those properties to be filtered are in array a.

Is there any easier way to do using underscore.

```
var a = [{
  name: "code"
}, {
  name: "barcode"
}, { 
  name: "status",
  type: "button"
}];

var b = [{
  id: 1,
  code: 10,
  barcode: "121212",
  status: "success",
  amount: "10",
  available: true
}, {
  id: 1,
  code: 10,
  barcode: "121212",
  status: "success",
  amount: "10",
  available: true
}];
```

Now if using underscore how can I get below result

```
var c = [{
  code: 10,
  barcode: "121212",
  status: "success"
}, {
  code: 10,
  barcode: "121212",
  status: "success"
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function( property, x, y ) {
  var filters = _.pluck( x, property );
  var filter = function( obj ) {
    return _.pick( obj, filters );
  };
  return _.map( y, filter );
})( 'name', a, b );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filters = _.pluck(a, 'name');

var c = _.map(b, function(el) {
    return _.pick(el, filters);
});
```